# hide product image on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use illustrations for as my product images. However, if you click on an illustration in product archive you get to the single product page. In single product page I want to hide the illustration and show the real image. I tried this from another forum but it is not working...

[www.momomai.ch/bento_shop](http://www.momomai.ch/bento_shop)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_gallery_attachment_ids', 'so_31818331_filter_gallery', 10, 2 );

function so_31818331_filter_gallery( $ids, $product ){
    
if (is_product()) {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post, $ids[0] );
        unset($ids[0]);
    }
    else {
        set_post_thumbnail( $post, end($ids));
    }
    return $ids;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please add an error that occurrs?

Comment: Thank you! There is no error, it is just showing the product image like before...